# Large numbers in small systems

Tags: computational-number-theory

Can we ever know the sum of the first $10^{10^{100}}$ digits of $\pi$?

Can we calgulate the $n$th digit of $\pi$ when the Kolmogorov-complexity of $n$ is larger than the complexity of the calculating system?

Example: We cannot calculate digit number 314159265358 of $\pi$ on a typical pocket calculator.

EDIT: As Goldstern remarks, we cannot write down all the digits simultaneously. But can we know every desired shorter string of digits, for instance the first billion following the digit number $10^{{10}^{90}}$ and then note their sum, and so on?

Comment: I don't see a mathematical question here, but perhaps I'm just blind.


Comment: The second question is along the lines of http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=46 -- we take a number which is so large as to be uncomputable with and ask whether we can compute some very trivial aspect of it. (See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271834/what-properties-of-busy-beaver-numbers-are-computable ). No one seems to have made much progress on either of those questions.

Comment: The sum of the first $10^{10^{100}}$ digits of $\pi$ has most likely  more than $10^{80}$ digits, so where would you write it down? 

Comment: That is just implied by my question: If matheamtics is primarily communication between inhabitants of the universe, does this sum belong to mathematics? Or is the "universe of discourse" larger?

Comment: Given your name, perhaps you will understand when I answer your questions, "Frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn." 

Comment: @Goldstern: Of course we cannot write all the digits. But can we know every desired shorter string of digits, for instance the first billion following the digit number $10^{{10}^{1000}}$ and then note their sum, and so on?